# Validating hierarchical objects with FluentValidation fails due to a hidden property

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a set of base DTOs without Id property (for creating objects) and i have a corresponding set of regular DTOs (inheriting from base and extending by Id column). Additionally those DTOs contain subobject with exactly the same approach - DeviceBaseDto contains VehicleBaseDto (without id), DeviceDto contains VehicleDto (inheriting from VehicleBaseDto and adding id property).

```
 public class DeviceBaseDto
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public VehicleBaseDto Vehicle {get;set;}

        //a lot more properties
    }

public class DeviceDto : DeviceBaseDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public new VehicleDto Vehicle { get; set; }

}
```

Now let's move to validator objects. What i'm trying to achieve is to contain all baseDto rules in base validator object. Then i put additional rules (for properties in inheriting class) in a regular validator.

```
public class DeviceBaseValidator<TDeviceBase> : AbstractValidator<TDeviceBase> where TDeviceBase : DeviceBaseDto
    {
        public DeviceBaseValidator()
        {
           RuleFor(x => x.Vehicle).SetValidator(new VehicleBaseValidator<VehicleBaseDto>());
           RuleFor(x => x.Vehicle).NotNull();
           //a lot of validation
        }
}}
public class DeviceValidator : DeviceBaseValidator<DeviceDto>
{
    public DeviceValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).GreaterThan(0);
    }
}

public class VehicleValidator : VehicleBaseValidator<VehicleDto>
{
    public VehicleValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).GreaterThan(0);
    }
}
```

When i try to run validation:

```
var deviceValidator = new DeviceValidator();
var validationResult = deviceValidator.Validate(deviceDto);
```

it fails stating that VehicleDto is null. Because we used "new" keyword in DeviceDto class for Vehicle property, it expects to get VehicleBaseDto but it gets VehicleDto instead. In other words, VehicleValidatorBase fails on:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Vehicle).NotNull();
```

but if i put exactly the same rule in VehicleValidator it will pass the validation. So what i want is:

- when DeviceDto will be received, i want DeviceValidator to run DeviceValidatorBase on DeviceDtoBase properties and VehicleValidatorBase rules on DeviceDto.Vehicle property.
- i want to run any extension rules from VehicleValidator on DeviceDto.Vehicle as well as all other rules on DeviceDto using DeviceValidator.

Perhaps the design i've created isn't exactly great so i'll be grateful to hear any advices on how to structure those objects.

Comment: Seems like you can make use of some `interface`s to help make your objects more mutable. For example, if you have an `IVehicle` that your `VehicleBaseDto` inherits from, you can then use `public IVehicle Vehicle {get;set;}` in your `DeviceBaseDto` class. Also, consider marking it as `virtual`.